# Input can only be string

Tags: java, swing, equals

I'm making a JOptionpane where the user can has to enter hes name. So it can't be empty and it can't be a number

The empty part is working but now I have to find a solution for the number part

As you can see in my code I made a while loop to check if "naam" isn't empty. Now I need to find a way to check if "naam" isn't a number.

```
String naam = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Geef uw naam in: ");

while (naam.equals("")) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Geef een naam in", "Geef naam", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   naam = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Geef uw naam in: ");
```

Comment: I would create a custom `JDialog` and apply a `DoumentListener` on the `JTextField` in which the `JButton` is disabled until the `JTextField` has a valid input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to check if it contains any digits. The regex "\\D" in java stands for a non-digit, and "+" stands for 1 or more. So you can change your while loop to:

```
while (!naam.matches("\\D+"))
```

This will include the empty equals check, as you need to have at least one non-digit for it to match.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply filter the input directly at the dialog, instead of messing about having to display error dialogs and re-showing the dialog...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class TestOptionPane08 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestOptionPane08();
    }

    public TestOptionPane08() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextField name = new JTextField(10);
                ((AbstractDocument) name.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
                    public String filter(String text) {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.length());
                        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                            if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
                                sb.append(c);
                            }
                        }
                        return sb.toString();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
                        super.insertString(fb, offset, filter(string), attr);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                        String filter = filter(text);
                        super.replace(fb, offset, length, filter, attrs);
                    }
                });

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name, "Name Please", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now, you could add the `JTextField` to `JPanel` and add a `JLabel` as well and even error messages...

Comment: I don't like to mess about ;)

Comment: +1 I'm just afraid a beginner will have a hard time understanding it.

Comment: `c != ' '` makes the input only one word?

Comment: Ah, mis-read the question, thought it could have spaces (it actually can't be empty...)

Comment: Besides, I don't see the problem ;) (that's a joke BTW)

Comment: Thanks for the great piece of code, I'm afraid I won't be able to use it since it's yet to complicated for me to fully understand it. I appreciate your help! I was able to solve the problem with Regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
 if (naam.matches("\\d+")) {/*it is a number*/}
```

[`String.matches(regexp)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) returns `true` if the string matches the regular expression given as parameter. In this example, `\\d+` matches one or more digits.

You may try other patterns in order to disallow strings with invalid characters (such as "`My#name`") but that depends on your definition of "name character".

For instance `[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\\s[A-Z][a-z]*)` matches strings with one or more sequences of an uppercase character followed by zero-or-more lowercase characters, each sequence separated by a single space, such as `My Name Is X`.